# Why can't I comment?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

OK, when I am on the main site, why am I not able to comment on a question?

See http://i39.tinypic.com/htz4lx.jpg (I chose a random new question, nothing special).

I had to name it a certain tag in order to post this so I picked support. I hope it's OK, but the comments, I believe, are correct.

Comment: Surprised no one has mentioned that this feature is counterintuitive. 
So another user posts an issue, and a solution is offered, which they accept and upvote. I have a clarification to add to the solution, basically to say "you can do this, but sometimes you should do this other thing"

WHY do i need rep to make that statement? It should be deletable by the original author, right? or at least Downvote-able? but why make me ask enough questions on this site just to accrue rep if all i want to do is add content to an existing post?

Answer (score 4):

You need 50 reputation to comment on other people's questions and the corresponding answers.

From [Privileges - Comment Everywhere - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment):

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on *other people's* posts is a privilege.

Comment: While this is true, his screen-shot makes me think he is also logged out. I think those Yes/No boxes only appear to anonymous users (not logged in) because they can't vote up/down.

Comment: [He currently has 1 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1159294/smarty57).

Comment: I was logged in

Comment: This is very bad this that new people can not answer

Comment: @MindaugasMilius: New users can post *answers*; they just cannot post comments.